# R commander installation on OS X 10.6

Tags: r, package, installation, r-commander

I'm a beginner in R. I installed R (3.2.1) and Rstudio on my Mac OS X 10.6. I am trying to install the R commander package, which seems to be quite a common package. Default repo to look for is CRAN.

> install.packages('Rcmdr')
>   package 'Rcmdr' is not available ( for R 3.2.1 )

I look for the a Rcmdr_XXX.tar.gz source compatible with R < 3.2.1 and try to install it from there, but many dependencies are also not found during the process so it also breaks.

I cannot imagine that the solution is adding manually every one of the not-found dependencies, is there an appropiate repo for OS X 10.6?

Comment: This is a pretty old set-up you have. Can't you upgrade your OS to a newer version? If that is not possible, you could download the first release of Rcmdr after R 3.2.1 was released [from here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcmdr/) (probably the one released on [2015-08-19](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcmdr/Rcmdr_2.2-0.tar.gz)) and build that from source on your computer.

Comment: Thanks Jaap, I was indeed trying to install it from the provided source. The problem is that it has many dependencies that try to install other packages, and those ones are not found again, so I would need to follow the exposed approach for dozens of packages. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, but your `install.packages` statement does not match the message (which says 'Rcm**c**dr'). Are you sure you spelled it correctly the first time around? It is a common mistake after all.

Comment: Yes, it was well spelled in R, the typo is only in the transcription here. Installing it from source seems to follow a logic process, but needs to find many other package dependencies that are not  found on the repository thus not installed.

Comment: R 3.2.1 is several years old. You will probably need to read the Rcmdr DESCRIPTION file and then also the DESCRIPTION files for all of the dependencies, and their dependencies as well, so that you can develop a list of packages needed. You will also need the have the right Xcode installed. The package archive is here ( Archive) https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive